# Monitor processes solution

Tags: bash, process

Scenario:

- Linux machine ;
- I need to "monitor" my processes: need to find every processes that is consuming >80% CPU over 20 seconds, and write the process info into a log .

Is there already a solution for this, or I'll write my own script ?
I've already have a small script, but I wanted to know If i can find something more advanced .

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution you can use is munin: http://munin-monitoring.org/

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that might be useful is 'lastcomm' which is in the acct package in Ubuntu.  It will show you how long processes run for.  For hardcore, detailed data you can use 'auditd'.